# How to display image on specific coordinates in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have this dialog window class in Qt:

```
class Board : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Board(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Board();

private:
    Ui::Board *ui;

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
};
```

I want to dislay a png image on user given coordinates in function `mousePressEvent`, which is called every time user clicks somewhere on the dialog window. So I need something like `displayImage("path/to/image.png", coordX, coordY);`. How can I do it?

The new code:

```
class Board : public QDialog
{
public:
    Board(QWidget *parent = 0) : 
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Board),
    view(&scene) 
{ 
    // Set background image
    /**************/
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QPixmap pix("path/background.png");
    ui->label_board->setPixmap(pix);

    /**************/
    / Set layout for displaying other images on the background
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(&view);
    //or set the layout and the view in the designer if using Qt Creator
}

protected:
virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent) override
{
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("path/to/image.png"));
    scene.addItem(item);
    item->setPos(coordX, coordY);
}

private:
    Ui::Board *ui;
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view;
};
```

The `label_board` is a label 500x500 set to some position with Qt Designer.

[image]

Comment: It's not totally clear what you are trying to do, and the code you are showing us does nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry, thought I was clear. I tried to explain better. And yes, the code does nothing because I'm asking you how to do something I can't, so how can I write it to my question?

Comment: I think you did a good job with your edits actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `QGraphicsView` ([docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html)) and `QGraphicsScene` ([docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html)):

```
class Board : public QDialog
{
public:
    Board(QWidget *parent = 0) : 
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Board),
        view(&scene) 
    { 
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        layout->addWidget(&view);
        //or set the layout and the view in the designer if using Qt Creator

        //EDIT: add background like this first
        QGraphicsPixmapItem *background = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("path/to/background.png"));
        scene.addItem(background);
        background.setPos(0, 0); //position it to cover all the scene so at 0,0 which is the origin point
        background.setScale(2.0); //scale the image to the scene rectangle to fill it
        background.setZValue(-0.1); //to ensure it is always at the back
    }

protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent) override
    {
        QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("path/to/image.png"));
        scene.addItem(item);
        item->setPos(coordX, coordY);
    }

private:
    Ui::Board *ui;
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view;
};
```

And that is pretty much it. Also note that the position is that of upper left corner of the item (image). If you would want to center it you would need to adjust the position based on the proportions of the item (image).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem now is that I already have a label with an image in the dialog window displayed and I'd like the new image (the one you showed me how to display it) to be displayed on the top of the mentioned label so the label would be a static background and the other images I'd like to add and remove as I need to. I'll add it to the code above.

Comment: @T.Syk You can set the background image of the QGraphicsScene in the same fashion. I would strongly encourage using the QGraphicsScene for all of the image rendering. QLabel approach is possible but is meant for different purposes (not to serve as background to be further worked on like a board. So simply add the background yourself to the scene in the same way I have shown first.

Comment: @T.Syk I have edited my answer to cover the background image as well in the constructor of the dialogue. You may also setBackgroundBrush() on the scene. Additionally you may want to adjust the background's z pozition (setZValue) to something like -0.1 to ensure the background will always be in the background and not obscuring whatever you added later.

Comment: I tried it to do it this way but the solution has two problems which I can't solve. The first one is the size of the layout. It resizes somehow strangely, when I click to the right down corner it moves. The second problem is displaying of the images in mousePressEvent function. When I click somewhere, the image shows a few centimeters away, but after clicking to the right down corner they start to display correctly and after resizing of the window they display incorrectly again. It's hard to explain, video would be better.

Comment: What I'd like to have is a window with fixed size, the background picture would be on some position and when I click somewhere on the window the next image displays on that position.

Comment: @T.Syk So what is the problem? Set the QGraphicsView to be the only widget in the layout, give layout no padding space so it takes all of the window, set it to fixed size (yours 500x500) and add the background image as I have described. It would literally be 2 or 3 extra lines in the code I have provided or none if you did it all in the designer.

Comment: It seems I'm getting to it, thanks, but I just can't figure out how to set layout to a fixed size.

Comment: @T.Syk You do not set layout to any size. Layout stretches with the widget so you must set the widget size (QDialog in your case). See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight

Comment: I added a picture of my app. I want the layout to be just under the grid. The black balls are the images which should be placed in `mousePressEvent` function. The place next to the grid will be used for other buttons. Is it possible? Or should I find any other approach to do what I want?

Comment: It certainly is possible but you should first familiarize with Qt Graphics Framework http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html It is even possible to embed widgets into the scene so what you describe is possible. However you have already drifterd very very far from your original question...